# Cancel request for Alamofire image

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofireimage

**Basic Information:**
I have a tableView and each tableView cell **containing an image and few labels**.
I use tableView **prefetch data** method to make API calls to fetch data as the tableView scrolls.

**Issue:**
Sometimes I see **a particular cell showing an image of some other cell**. 
This happens when I scroll a little faster than normal speed.
Note: In order to overcome from this issue I just need to scroll the tableView up/down

**Things tried:**
I have set the imageView to nil in **prepare for reuse** method.

**The conclusion I have reached:**
By debugging the issue I understood that once a cell is visible I make an image request using Alamofire Image but I scroll it before we received the response. 
So, what might be happening is that on receiving a response it is setting an image for the cell but that cell is not visible as I am reusing the cells. The cell contains some other data.

Please let me know how can I cancel the request if the cell is not visible.
Let me know if I am missing something in the question.

Comment: in this case better you can use some framework like . Kingfisher, Haneke etc. bcoz very soon you end up in caching the image, memory issues etc. those are all handled by the above pods.

Comment: I think those are handled by AlamofireImage

Comment: AlamofireImage handles fetching and caching, but these libs can give much more than that. like setting image async in the cell - its free in these pods. feel free to check

Comment: bwt canceling wont solve your problem, if you want the image again you will end up in fetching again.

Answer (score 1):

What I do in this situation is set the cell's tag to match the row number.

When the image requests complete, I check if it still has the same tag (if it was reused, tag would be changed).

Something like this, in `cellForRowAt indexPath`:

```
cell.tag = indexPath.row
ImageService.shared.getImage(completion: { (image) in
  if let image = image, cell.tag == indexPath.row {
    //apply image
  }
}
```

This doesn't cancel the request, but it ignores the result if the cell is not in the same position anymore.

Comment: This solution is working thanks. But the only issue is that if you have a long list and user scroll it fast, the `placeholder` will be shown for a long time before all requests will be not finished. Anyway, that is better than 100 times of image change. Also, I prefer to set `tag` to `UiImageView`, not to `Cell`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because tableView reuse the cells and if it having a image downloading in queue and you scroll and the downloading is complete, it shows the downloaded image for few second until correct image download.

use placeholder in `af_setImage` method. it will solve your problem

```
imageView.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: img)!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "product_placeholder")
```

Comment: This will not help in the mentioned situation. As each time the placeholder will be changed with a new image and if you will scroll fast there will be an image show.